# unable to get attribute from event handler "this" object

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<select onchange="alert($(this).attr('data-type'))">
    <option data-type="1" value="a">a</option>
    <option data-type="2" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

When I run that on jsfiddle I get null. Any ideas?

Here's the js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/49wyG/

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a jQuery solution: http://jsfiddle.net/49wyG/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` refers to the `select` not the `option`. Try this instead:

```
<select>
    <option data-type="1" value="a" onclick="alert($(this).attr('data-type'))">a</option>
    <option data-type="2" value="b" onclick="alert($(this).attr('data-type'))">b</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively you could use the `:selected` selector or `this.selectedIndex` to grab the `option`. Something like this:

```
<select onchange="alert($(':selected',this).attr('data-type'))" >
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to grab the selected index of the element and go from there, try this:

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-type'));">
    <option data-type="1" value="a">a</option>
    <option data-type="2" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

Works good on my end.

Answer (score 2):

The `data-type` attributes are on the option elements not the select. I assume you want the data type of the currently selected one

```
<select onchange="alert($(this).find(':selected').attr('data-type'))">
    <option data-type="1" value="a">a</option>
    <option data-type="2" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49wyG/4/

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this...

```
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-type'))">
    <option data-type="1" value="a">a</option>
    <option data-type="2" value="b">b</option>
</select>
```

the "this" object on the change event is the list, not the option